# What does "ni tsuki" mean in the title "Sono otoko, kyōbō ni tsuki"?

Tags: translation

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violent_Cop), the Japanese title of the film "Violent Cop", "その男、凶暴につき" ("Sono otoko, kyōbō ni tsuki"), literally means "That man, being violent". Is this correct? What other translations could there be for "ni tsuki"?

Comment: That is a free translation, not a literal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this correct? >> Yes I think it is. It means "その男は凶暴なので"/"その男は凶暴だから".

The particle は is left out. につき(に就き) means なので/だから, "because~", "since~". につき sounds more literary than なので. (The に is a particle.) So it's like "Because the man is violent (you got to stay away from him etc..)"

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/167354/m0u/ >> 2
or
http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/0/0ss/114908800000/ >> 3

Comment: I don't think that translation is correct, "being violent".

Comment: Oh.. OK, maybe the problem is my English... Then, how would you translate it? What would it be like if it's その男、凶暴につき、抹殺(されました)。or その男、凶暴につき、隔離(されています)。?

Comment: I don't think the problem is your English, the problem is the English of the translation, "being violent".

Answer (score -2):

Nitsuki is a small Ivory carving worn on a japanes murchants belt sash to hold a money purse.

Comment: Do you have a source? Do you think this meaning is relevant here?